# Can a super conducting magnet & gravity create a cheap source of energy?

Tags: superconductivity

I have a question about whether this would produce a cheap source of energy. If you created two superconductive magnets configured in a figure of eight layout, in a cold enough environment so you needed no extra power for cooling and the magnets would be in persistent state (so after initial charge would need no extra power). If you then made these magnets levitate a very heavy piece of iron could you then use the gravity of the earth (or moon if the experiment was set up on the cold moon) to generate power when then power was switched from one magnet to the other magnet. E.g. The iron block 1 would rise, power would move to magnet 2, iron block 1 would fall (maybe turning a flywheel on the way down), iron block 2 would rise etc. In my mind this configuration would not cost any additional energy ( as long as the environment was cold enough) and you could get virtually free energy by utilising the gravitational field of the earth or moon... Has this idea got legs?

Comment: It is not cheap to cool anything to superconductivity temperatures (or perhaps there may be some OK-ish high $T_c$ superconductors, but those are expensive to produce anyways).

Comment: There is also no way around cooling *something*, be it the magnets directly or the environment. This already will lose you more energy than you stand to gain.

Comment: Let's say we build this in on the moon where it is already very cold. I appreciate we would need to get the kit there, but if it were set up in a very cold environment would it not work?

Comment: Don't think about the set-up costs, can it be setup so when it runs the energy would be cheap and virtually free? I say it can!

Comment: -233 Celsius at night on the moon...

Comment: Your question basically boils down to the following: Does superconductivity violate conservation of energy? Answer: Predictably, nope.

Comment: Tell me why this would not work then? I would also like to think nope, but my head says once this was setup it would run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first come up with an infinitely cheap high temperature superconducting magnet, with a lossless switching circuit - now we can focus on the real issue.

We have one loop with current, and one without; now we throw the switch. Iron block 1 (a magnet, I assume) is held up for a minute (we are going to lower it and extract gravitational energy in a minute), but block 2 will be pushed up. Now let's look at the magnetic field in coil 2. It will be the magnetic field from the current in the loop, minus the magnetic field due to the permanent magnet (since they are repelling, this makes the field in the region where they repel smaller). Now total energy stored in a magnetic field is proportional to the integral of $B^2$ over the entire volume - so when the field cancels in some places, the energy stored in the field is less. The principle of virtual work tells us that a good way to calculate the force on the magnet is to see how the amount of stored energy changes with a small change in the position of the magnet - the "virtual work done" divided by the infinitesimal displacement is the force. And block 2 will rise until no further net force - in other words, when the maximum amount of energy has been extracted from the magnetic field.

And so, when you switch the current back to loop 1, the amount of energy that is available to energize loop 1 is less. At every cycle you will extract energy from the superconductor, until nothing is left.

Conservation of energy. It's an annoying law that keeps getting in the way of a good *perpetuum mobile*.

Answer (score 2):

How do you get the superconductor to levitate the iron in the first place?  You have to input energy to do so.  The energy required to do that will be more than the energy that you can harvest from letting it fall.

You can't generate energy in this way.

Comment: These would be magnets in a persistent mode - no further power required. Could they not then use effects such as Meissner effect to produce the levitation and then generate the power?

Comment: No, once you couple it to something non-superconducting to extract energy you lose the 'magic' of just being able to run forever without power loss, precisely because you're getting energy out of it.

Comment: You are asking another question, not really answering the original one (except by saying "you can't").